# Spring MVC how do you return <select> value as the form/model value?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I may be going about this the wrong way but I'm writing an app that starts with a simple page with a drop down select and then progresses based on the selection.  As I'm using spring MVC I thought the easiest solution would be to set the select value as the object itself but it seems to to be returning Null.

So the initial home page controller is

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController  extends JFrame { 

@Autowired
private FruitDAO fruitDAO;

 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String HomePage(Model model) {

        List<Fruit> fruit = fruitDAO.ListAll();
        model.addAttribute("fruits", fruits);

        return "Home";
    }
```

which opens page Home.jsp

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
    <html>
    <body>
    <form method="POST" commandName="fruitForm" > 
    <h2>Choose a fruit</h2>

    <select id="fruits" name=Fruits >
    <c:forEach var="fruit" items="${fruits}" >
       <option value="${fruit}" >${fruit[1]} (ID: ${fruit[0]})</option>
    </c:forEach>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="View" />

    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I'm then currently just wanting this to return a post to the same controller (later to be redirected).

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String processFruitSelection(@ModelAttribute("fruitForm") Fruit fruit) {
        // for testing purpose:
        System.out.println("Fruit: " + fruit.getName());

        //curretly a dummy hello world page
        return "TestPage";
 }
```

Fruit is obviously a dummy entity but essentially the model has 4 basic attributes (3 string and one date).  At the moment it is returning null.  I'm guessing the form object returned isn't actually just the selected value.

I would be grateful if anyone could tell me if I there is a way of making the selected value the form value returned or if I have taken completely the wrong approach!?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some errors in your existing code :
1. In home page controller you are adding fruits instead of fruit(List name)
2. In Home.jsp, in option, fruit is variable, not an array

Solution is you have to use `form:form`,`form:select` and `form:option` like this :
Here `meeting` is your model attribute and `meetings` is your list

```html
<form:form action="controllerName" method="POST" modelAttribute="meeting">
   <form:select path="country">
     <form:option value="NONE" label="Select" />
     <form:options items="${meetings}" />
   </form:select>
</form:form>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I've followed this advice but still have an error.  I've edited with  the new code - any chance you could have a quick look and see if you can spot the error ?

Comment: You have to use either `commandName` or `modelAttribute` because both are same, better to use `modelAttribute`. You have to pass object name in modelAttribute like `meeting` which you will get as model object in action servlet(controller). In `<form:form>` tag you have to mention action url of controller.

Comment: Thanks  actually my get was in the incorrect format (getName not getFruitName)

Answer (score 2):

you should use spring form tag in jsp instead of simple form tag.
also use `<form:input>` and all provided by spring.

```
<form:form modelAttribute="fruits" method="POST">
```